# How do I set an IText7 fallback font?

Tags: java, itext7

How do I set an IText7 fallback font? That is: A font which is used as a fallback font in cases where the primary font don't have a specific code point.

My original code just used PdfFontFactory.createFont(...) to get a PdfFont, and then I just called setFont on the Text element where I wanted to change font. This worked as in the text was shown with the expected font, but I could not find any way to specify a fallback font.

So I changed my code, so now I start by creating a new FontProvider and then call addFont(...) with all the fonts I need, including the fallback font.

And then I add this font provider to the document.

I then call setFontFamily on the Text objects where I want to change the font, and this works. Including fallback to the first added font, in cases where the primary font don't have the specified codepoint.

But is this the correct way to handle this issue?

This solution does have one new problem. It always embed the fonts in the pdf documents and I can't find a way to prevent this. None of the addFonts or setFontFamily methods have a flag to specify if the font should be embeded.

The FontProvider does have a method called getDefaultEmbeddingFlag() which always return true, so I tried to create a new Class which extended FontProvider and changed getDefaultEmbeddingFlag to just return false. But even when I use this class as FontProvider the font still get embeded.

So I guess my main question is: How do I enable fallback to a different font for unknown code points, while still having the ability not to embed fonts?.